# HtmlUnit document.location

Tags: java, htmlunit

I have a some HtmlPage with following script:

```
<script>
    document.location = http://myotherpage.com
</script>
```

I created it with this code:

```
HtmlPage htmlPage = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPageCreator().createPage(webResponse, webClient.getCurrentWindow());
```

"http://myotherpage.com" sends 302 redirect to the other page. How I could create other pages/windows? One with 302 redirect and second that is a result of this redirect?